# remove final '/' char from hashtag url

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a situation that I won't be able to apply htaccess on, particularly this URL:

`www.site.com/#hash`

which triggers an important js function.

Some referrers are sending traffic to www.site.com/#hash/ <-- notice the trailing slash

I need a quick-fix solution (PHP would be my first choice, and JS second) that will strip away any final '/' from the URL while leaving any kind of hash (e.g., /#hash1, #hash2, #otherhash, etc.) intact.

I've tried a few dozen things and so far I still haven't found a good way to target/modify/remove only the '/' and nothing else.

For example, I'm pretty sure this could work:

```
$url = preg_replace('{/$}', '', $url);
```

...but I don't know how to aim it at the actual url in the browser's address bar.

And, with JS, for example, pseudocode:

```
if (window.location.hash.CONTAINS == '/') {window.location.hash = ''}
```

In this case I can't figure out how to target only the possible '/' at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that can't be solved in PHP. You must use JavaScript.

Use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
if (location.hash.indexOf('/') != -1) {
    // remove the slash
    location.hash = location.hash.replace('/', '');
}
```

If it needs to be specifically the last slash:

```
if (location.hash.substr(-1) == '/') {
    location.hash = location.hash.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Comment: That does a poor job of leaving the hash intact

Comment: @Paulpro That didn't seem to be a requirement, but updated anyway.

Comment: hash and url manipulation always kicks my ass, so thanks for bailing me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to do a regex substitution:

```
window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(/\/$/, '');
```